# Unbound Local Error Issue

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have seen other posts about this but I am a beginner and don't understand most of the other ones I have seen about this. If someone could explain what to do and how it works it would be appreciated! Here is the code.

```
import time
import sys 
import random
done = False
day = 1
v = 2
v2 = 2
gas = 2
gas2 = 2
# thrist
dt = 0
dt2 = 0
# hunger
dh = 0
dh2 = 0
#sanity
ds = 100
ds2 = 100
#water
water = 5
water2 = 5
#food
food = 5
food2 = 5
def cls():
  for i in range(10):
    print('\n' * 100)
title = input('Press ENTER to start.')
cls()
playercount = input('How many players are playing?')
def player1():
  start = input('''
  Objective: Survive the nuke drop for 30 days.
  Items: 
    - Food
      + 5
    - Water
      + 5
    - Gas Mask
    - Medkit
    - Gun
      + 1 ammo
    - Axe
    - Board Games
  Survivors:
    - You
  ''')
  cls()
  time.sleep(2)
  while not done:
    if dt > 5 and dt < 10:
      input('You are getting thirsty.')
    if dh > 5 and dh < 10:
      input('You are getting hungry.')
    if ds > 50 and ds < 70:
      input('You are starting to go insane!')
    if dt > 15:
      input('You died of thirst')
      sys.exit()
    if dh > 15:
      input('You died of hunger!')
      sys.exit()
    if ds < 50:
      input('You became insane!')
      sys.exit()
```

here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 892, in <module>
    player1()
  File "main.py", line 261, in player1
    if dt > 5 and dt < 10:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dt' referenced before assignment
```

This is happening multiple times throughout my code any tips help!

Comment: Do you have a `dt=<something>` statement before the code you showed above?

Comment: Yes I do outside of the while loop.

Comment: You should include the entire text of the function.

Comment: When I do that people say to only put what I need but I will edit it

Comment: @Fiix where are you calling player1() function

Comment: at the bottom of the code

Comment: @Fiix no ur not. There is no caller there.

Comment: not at the bottom of the pasted code

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function and if that function has a variable which is not imported in through argument or not declared inside it; then such error occurs.

When you call your function `player1()` ,python couldn't found the variable `dt`, because you've declared it outside the scope where you're trying to use it. Either take `dt` inside function with argument or declare it inside `player1()` function.

Also do same for `ds` and `dh` variables.

Comment: So I took it out of the function and into an if statement but the same error appears?

Comment: No, what i mean is take those vars' declaration  inside function so that during function's call, python could see them. or if you want them to be outside the function then make a parameter for function by which it can take those vars, like :-

Comment: And during calling that function put those vars like:-

player1(ds,dh,dt)